# Bulk Replace Missing Images in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I recently restored a backup to my Wordpress site, however, the backup did not contain some images for the posts, therefore now some of these posts show no image or featured image at all whereas the Media Library in Wordpress Dashboard shows empty placeholders against the image names.

I tried to install Replace Media extension from Plugins library of Wordpress, however it only allows me to replace the images one-by-one which is a hectic process since there are hundreds of images that need to be replaced.

I want a single image to be replaced on all of these images, it will be a image showing the logo of my website, therefore it will save me time from going through each post and replacing the image.

In a nutshell, I have a single Image. I want this image to replace all of the images I select from Media Library or I select from a date range, any of which is possible.

Awaiting your kind responses. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this answer to show image for posts that don't have featured image:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/64813

If you want a plugin, please try this one:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/default-featured-image/

Comment: Is there an extension that specifically allows me to set a specific image on all posts that do not have any featured image?

Comment: Try this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/quick-featured-images/

Comment: Is there any alternative to Quick Featured Images. I see the option for adding featured images for the posts having no featured image set, but the plugin is throwing the following error (The site is experiencing technical difficulties. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions.). Is there any alternative?

Comment: Can you please let me know what's sent to your email regarding this issue?

Comment: @user3206911 I've updated the answer with another plugin recommendation